# ¿Cómo redirigir una sola página a la página principal temporalmente con .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Tengo que poner una URL de ayuda en una App, pero no he tenido tiempo de crear la página de esa URL, por eso quiero redirigir mientras tanto a la página principal, pero no me funciona.

He intentando todas las redirecciones que siguen y ninguna funciona:

- `Redirect 301 /miapp/ayuda/ https://www.midominio.com/miapp`
- `Redirect 301 /miapp/ayuda/ https://www.miapp.midominio.com`
- `Redirect 301 /miapp/ayuda/ index.php`
- `Redirect 301 /miapp/ayuda/ miapp`

Lo raro es que tampoco me da un error 404, sino un error 500:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@miapp.midominio.com
>   to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while
>   trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Tengo otras redirecciones que funcionan, pero ninguna es a la página principal, sino a otras páginas:

```
Redirect 301 /miapp/category/test/ /miapp/test/
```

Estoy en un entorno Wordpress, y tengo una instalación dentro de `miapp` que funciona como un sitio independiente dentro del dominio principal.

Comment: prueba con -->  Redirect 301 / https://www.midominio.com/miapp

Comment: perdón no leí todo, si la redirección es desde una página en particular hacia otra tendrías que poner **Redirect 301 /index.html/la_pagina.html http://pagina2.html/esta_pagina.html**

Comment: No funciona @SebastiánMiranda.

Comment: Cuando dices que quieres redirigir a tu página principal, te refieres a una dentro del mismo dominio? si ese es el caso sería **Redirect /pagina.html /index.html**, es la redirección más básica, si pruebas con esto te sigue saliendo el error? Lo que si, tendrías que respetar si por ejemplo tu pagina está en index.html/preguntas/pagina.html hacia /index.html

Comment: te dejo este [link](https://wpscholar.com/blog/simple-redirects-with-htaccess/) en donde tienen varios ejemplos